# How to insert a PDF link in a FAQ widget?

Tags: cms, html, widget, wysiwyg

I'm new so I don't know how things really work here but I'm going to give it a try :

I would like to know if there's a way to insert a PDF link in an FAQ widget. I used HTML coding in the WYSIWYG (am I correct?) with the code "<"a href='' >" but it did not work out.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks.

Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento has some file restrictions for the WYSIWYG editor. You can add PDF as file extension with the following DI snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

You will find the di.xml like so:

```
MODULE_VENDOR/MODULE_NAME/etc/di.xml
```

or:

```
MODULE_VENDOR/MODULE_NAME/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
```